# Ruby: How to copy current running exe script to another folder?

Tags: ruby, file, copy, filesystems, exe

I need my .exe file, made by ocra to copy itself to another folder. I was trying to do it with FileUtils like this, using _ _FILE__, but it keeps kopying the .rbw file, not the .exe one.

FileUtils.cp(_ _FILE__, 'C:\Users\Public\Documents')

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the use case of an executable coyiing itself at runtime to a different location?

Comment: It is used tu install my program properly to users PC.

Comment: @defyay Well, ocra has a solution for [this usecase](https://github.com/larsch/ocra#creating-an-installer-for-your-application).

Answer (score 0):

You need `ENV["OCRA_EXECUTABLE"]`.

See the [doc](https://github.com/larsch/ocra#environment-variables).